# Securing GitHub's Personal access tokens

Tags: github, github-api

I am developing a web application. Which needs to get file content from an organization's private GitHub repository. So I choose the [GitHub API to read content from GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#contents) and it needs personal access token for authentication. I have created a static token through the GitHub web as per [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token). stored it on the client-side to send along with every request to GitHub API

**Issue is**

Anyone can view this personal access token from request headers and misuse it.

**Question is**

Is any way to secure it?

Comment: Could you share more info on your implementation?  My guess is that you're sending this PAT to the client for it to then reach out to GitHub?  If instead your web app's backend were talking to GitHub (e.g. acting as a proxy between the client and GitHub) you wouldn't have that same issue.

Comment: @JohnLBevan  I am sending PAT to GitHub API from the client side. I  have hardcoded PAT in client side.

Comment: If the value's coming from the client side I'm not sure it's possible to be secure; any information that you want the client to send to GitHub has to be available to the client in order to be sent; and if it's available to the client, it's exposed.  Sometimes people get around such issues by issuing short lifetime tokens to the client which expire before any exposure's a significant risk; but that's not ideal and in this scenario I don't think it's even possible.  I'd recommend you rearchitect your solution so this secure info's sent from the server side directly to GitHub.

Comment: You can't secure it; the PAT is equivalent to your login+password.